# how to place tawk.io inside appp-root in angular 10?

Tags: angular, tawk.to

I am working with Angular 10. I need to place chat functionality after login. I am using tawk.to for chat.

I need to display chat section after login only. So if I am placing tawk.to script inside sub module then it's not showing chat section on GUI. But if I am placing tawk.to script on index.html inside body part then it's showing chat section on GUI. Even it's showing on login page.

So how can we make it possible like display chat section after login only. Under sub module in Angular 10.